# show $\frac{z}{(1+z)^2}$ is injective in the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, rouches-theorem

So I need to show that $\frac{z}{(1+z)^2}$ is injective in the unit disk, $\mathbb{D}$.

Here is what I have thought so far:

If $\frac{z}{(1+z)^2}$ is injective, then $\frac{z}{(1+z)^2} - c$ always have 1 solution in the unit disk for any $c \in \mathbb{C}$.

So I need to find the root of $\frac{z}{(1+z)^2} - c = 0$ or $\frac{z-c(1+z)^2}{(1+z)^2} = 0$ or $c(1+z)^2 -z = cz^2-(2c-1)z +c= 0$

I tried using Rouche's theorem, but all pairs of $f$ and $g$ that I tried failed the inequality $|f(z) - g(z)| < |f(z)|$ with $|z| = 1$.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to approach this question? Thanks.

Comment: It looks as if you are trying to prove surjectivity rather than injectivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f(z)=\frac{z}{(1+z)^2}$$ is injective on the open unit disk but it is not injective on the closed unit disk.

Note that $$f(i)=f(-i) = \frac {1}{2}$$

To show $f$ is injective on the open unit disk, assume $$ \frac{z}{(1+z)^2}=\frac{w}{(1+w)^2}$$

Cross multiply and factor to get $$(z-w)(1-zw)=0$$

Thus inside the unit disk, we get $z=w$ becaluse $zw\ne 1$

Comment: Sir, Can you say something about the surjectivity of $\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$ onto $\mathbb C$ from the open unit disc?     I am getting $\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}=w \neq 0 \Rightarrow z=\frac{2+\frac{1}{w}\pm \sqrt{\frac{4}{w}+\frac{1}{w^2}}}{2}$, but iam not sure $z$ in open unit disc.

Answer (score 2):

You said

> If $\frac{z}{(1+z)^2}$ is injective, then $\frac{z}{(1+z)^2} - c$ always have 1 solution in the unit disk for any $c \in \mathbb{C}$.

which is not correct (or at least, misleading). For *injectivity* you have to show that $f(z) = c$ has *at most* one solution, or equivalently, that $f(z) = f(w)$ implies $z=w$.

If $f(z) = c$ has *at least* one solution for all $c \in \Bbb C$ then it would be a *surjective* onto $\Bbb C$ (which it isn't, as shown below).

Here is a possible approach which demonstrates the injectivity and also determines the image of the unit disk under $f$:

$$
f(z) = \frac{z}{(1+z)^2} = \frac 14 - \frac 14\left( \frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^2 
$$
is the composition of three injective mappings:

- $f_1(z) = \frac{z-1}{z+1}$ is a Möbius transformation and maps the unit disk onto the left half-plane.
- $f_2(z) = z^2$ is injective in the left half-plane and maps it onto $\Bbb C \setminus  (- \infty, 0] $, i.e. the entire complex plane without the negative real axis.
- $f_3(z) = \frac{1-z}{4}$.

It follows that $f = f_3 \circ f_2 \circ f_1$ is a conformal (and in particular, injective) mapping from the unit disk onto the “slit domain” $\Bbb C \setminus  [\frac 14, \infty)$.

Your function $f$ is also known as  [“rotated Koebe function”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koebe_quarter_theorem#Koebe_function) (with $\alpha = -1$).